# How to get aggregate Cassandra rows data from java

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a table in Cassandra with the int column price and quantity and item.

Below are the table values:

item price quantity
 x.   10.    100
 y.   11.    200
 z.   12.    300
 w.   13.    400

Now when I fire a select query from java ex, price > 10,

it is returning 
{200,
300,
400}

but I need to aggregate data as {900}

I used sum() in thee query, but it is giving below exception.

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown function 'sum'
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException

I am unable to implement the aggregate function in java.

Comment: what cassandra and driver versions are you using?

Comment: How do your table definition and query look like?

Answer (score 1):

You must be using at least version 2.2 of cassandra for aggregation functions other than count.